# how to create a route knowing starting point, ending point and distance to travel

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to create a walk path on a map using python. And I need to set not only start point and end point, but distance to travel too. So I can not just create a shortest path from point to point.
I started with osmnx and networkx. I created different paths, but I can not check their distance. Can not find anything on that on documentation.

The idea is to make a telegram bot which would create a walking path, so the point is to walk for 5 km for example. Bot was easy, but I have no idea how to create a route based on distance I want to travel (with start and end points)

Comment: Let me clearly say that one more time. I want to set how many km I want to walk and set my starting and ending points. And then I want to create needed path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what the exact question is here, but as for:

> I started with osmnx and networkx. I created different paths, but I can not check their distance. Can not find anything on that on documentation.

This functionality is explained in both the OSMnx usage examples/documentation as well as the NetworkX documentation:

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

# get a graph, an origin, and a destination
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
orig, dest = list(G)[0], list(G)[-10]

# calculate the shortest path from origin to destination
path = nx.shortest_path(G, orig, dest, weight='length')

# the length of each edge traversed along the path
lengths = ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, path, 'length')

# the total length of the path
path_length = sum(lengths)

# or just directly calculate the shortest path's length from origin to destination
path_length = nx.shortest_path_length(G, orig, dest, weight='length')
```

If you want to find the shortest path at of least `L` length, you could use OSMnx's [k_shortest_paths](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.k_shortest_paths) function then iterate through the paths until you find one with length >= `L` (determining each's length as demonstrated in the code snippet above).

```py
L = 3400
paths = ox.k_shortest_paths(G, orig, dest, 1000, 'length')
for i, path in enumerate(paths):
    length = sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, path, 'length'))
    if length >= L:
        break
i, length, path
```

Comment: That kind of does the trick. But only on short distances. If I want to start and end my path at the same place and I want to walk a lot - this algorithm will take a hell of a lot of time to create all different paths
Can you advise anything with that?

Comment: For example: I want to walk 5000m
`paths = ox.k_shortest_paths(G, origin_node, destination_node, 1010, 'length')`

this will give me 1233.9 m
If I will increase k to 3000:
`paths = ox.k_shortest_paths(G, origin_node, destination_node, 3000, 'length')`
I would get 1260.129 m

Comment: Have you any ideas?